# Solving linear equations in vb6

Tags: vb6

I have to find out the integral solution of a equation ax+by=c such that all variables are greater than 0 and value of (x+y) is minimum. I have c++ implementation.. need it in vb6

```
void compute0(int &x,int &y,int a,int b,int c) // naive
{
    int xx,yy;
    xx = -1; yy = -1;
    for (y = 0;;y++)
    {
        x = c - b*y;
        if (x < 0) break; // y out of range stop
        if (x % a) continue; // non integer solution
        x /= a; // remember minimal solution
        if ((xx < 0) || (x + y <= xx + yy))
        { 
            xx=x; yy=y; 
        } 
    }
    x=xx; y=yy;
}
```

Comment: Do you understand the C++ code?  There is nothing special going on in that code.  Look up how to write for loops and do basic math operations in VB6!...

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. You are expected to show what you have attempted so far. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i dont understand c++, specially its operators

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you

```
Private Sub compute0(x As Long, y As Long, ByVal a As Long, ByVal b As Long, ByVal c As Long) 'naive
Dim xx          As Long
Dim yy          As Long
Dim continue    As Boolean

xx = -1
yy = -1
y = 0
continue = True

Do While continue
    x = c - b * y
    If (x < 0) Then 'y out of range stop
        Exit Do
    End If

    If (x Mod a) = 0 Then
        x = x / a 'remember minimal solution
        If ((xx < 0) Or (x + y <= xx + yy)) Then
            xx = x
            yy = y
        End If
    End If
    y = y + 1
Loop

x = xx
y = yy
End Sub
```

Make sure you test it before you use it.

Comment: @martha        No worries.  I've just had a thought, in the original answer I put the variables as integers, and I've just edited it so they are longs.  Make sure the VB6 code has them as longs.